# Is it possible to run an app directly from a USB flash drive (OTG)?

Tags: applications, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-s-6, usb-on-the-go

I'm almost giving up on this, can anyone help me?

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 which means that I can't get an external sd card mounted to my phone. So I bought an OTG flash drive with the hope that I can install or run apps and games from there so my storage problem is solved. But after researching on several forums I'm still getting no answer for this.

**Is it possible to run or install apps on a USB flash drive?**

Comment: Adoptable Storage will work for you, but then you cannot remove the OTG drive anymore. (Apps will start crashing)